# fancybox and jquery form validation

Tags: jquery-validate, fancybox, fancybox-2

Have problem with fancybox and jquery validate plugin when form is in fancybox container.

For examle (inline):
html:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  $.fancybox('
<form class="myform">
<input type="text" name="email" class="email" />

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
');
})
</script>
```

js file:

```js
$(".myform").validate(
          {
          rules: {
            email: "required",
            email: "email"
                 }
           }
        );
```

How to make jquery validation pluging to work in fancybox?

Comment: You must invoke `.validate()` _after_ the `form` is created.

Comment: you could initialize the validation plugin inside the fancybox's `beforeShow` callback

Comment: @JFK, I don't think `beforeShow` will work.  The `form` must be constructed before `.validate()` is called.  `afterLoad` is more appropriate.

Comment: @Sparky : `beforeShow` works pretty much fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/ZMEEW/1/

Comment: @JFK, indeed it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do two things...

1. Use the `afterLoad` FancyBox callback function to initialize `.validate()` immediately after the form is loaded.
2. Put the content for FancyBox in a hidden `div` instead of in your jQuery.  It's cleaner.

Note:  You may want to reconsider using `email` for the `name` attribute.  It has potential to cause great confusion since the rule is also called `email`.

**HTML**:

```html
<a id="test" href="#inline">Test</a>

<div style="display:none" id="inline">
    <form class="myform">
        <input type="text" name="email" class="email" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#test').fancybox({
        afterLoad: function() {
            $('.myform').validate({
                // rules and options for validate plugin,
                rules: {
                    email: {  // "email" is name of the field
                        required: true,
                        email: true // "email" is name of the rule
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZMEEW/**

Comment: you could always use `beforeShow` because the form is already constructed, not visible yet though

Comment: @JFK, ok, use either one.  Whatever.